# Sorting an array before inserting to database

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I hate to beat a dead horse, but here goes. I have an Apache2 server running and I create my own php/html forms for in and output with mysql. Works great, I love it.

My problem is I have a huge array that I want to insert to MySQL but it needs to be sorted first (0<00). I've gone through the many Q & A covering the subject here and the code supplied works on a single array just fine. However, I need to loop through about 7000 sets and I'd like the output to be in original format but I have had no luck making that work as desired.

```
$data = array(
    array(29,11,15,30,33),
    array(30,11,25,18,02),
    array(12,15,08,06,18),
    array(17,20,03,21,02),
    array(26,27,12,30,11),
    array(05,25,34,11,16),
    array(29,11,06,30,14),
    array(05,26,12,18,33),
    array(23,28,05,22,09),
    array(05,36,31,32,27),
    array(02,06,03,05,14)
);
```

Comment: Two questions: (1) sorted by what criteria? (2) Why does it need to be sorted *before* it hits MySQL?  That implies a problem with your database design.

Comment: Is that the source data?  Do you want the elements in each individual sub-array sorted, or the sub-arrays sorted within $data?  This is a very vague question as is . . .

Comment: I need to sort each set ascending, to maintain pattern for mysql query for pattern matching. If that makes sense.

Comment: Very nice. Too simple to see for me I guess. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to sort each sub array:

```
$data = array(
    array(29,11,15,30,33),
    array(30,11,25,18,02),
    array(12,15,08,06,18),
    array(17,20,03,21,02),
    array(26,27,12,30,11),
    array(05,25,34,11,16),
    array(29,11,06,30,14),
    array(05,26,12,18,33),
    array(23,28,05,22,09),
    array(05,36,31,32,27),
    array(02,06,03,05,14)
);

foreach($data as &$value){ // Mind the & byref value
    sort($value);
}

var_dump($data);
// $data is now sorted over here
```

The output:

```
array(11) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    int(11)
    [1]=>
    int(15)
    [2]=>
    int(29)
    [3]=>
    int(30)
    [4]=>
    int(33)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    int(2)
    [1]=>
    int(11)
    [2]=>
    int(18)
    [3]=>
    int(25)
    [4]=>
    int(30)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    int(0)
    [1]=>
    int(6)
    [2]=>
    int(12)
    [3]=>
    int(15)
    [4]=>
    int(18)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    int(2)
    [1]=>
    int(3)
    [2]=>
    int(17)
    [3]=>
    int(20)
    [4]=>
    int(21)
  }
  [4]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    int(11)
    [1]=>
    int(12)
    [2]=>
    int(26)
    [3]=>
    int(27)
    [4]=>
    int(30)
  }
  [5]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    int(5)
    [1]=>
    int(11)
    [2]=>
    int(16)
    [3]=>
    int(25)
    [4]=>
    int(34)
  }
  [6]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    int(6)
    [1]=>
    int(11)
    [2]=>
    int(14)
    [3]=>
    int(29)
    [4]=>
    int(30)
  }
  [7]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    int(5)
    [1]=>
    int(12)
    [2]=>
    int(18)
    [3]=>
    int(26)
    [4]=>
    int(33)
  }
  [8]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    int(0)
    [1]=>
    int(5)
    [2]=>
    int(22)
    [3]=>
    int(23)
    [4]=>
    int(28)
  }
  [9]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    int(5)
    [1]=>
    int(27)
    [2]=>
    int(31)
    [3]=>
    int(32)
    [4]=>
    int(36)
  }
  [10]=>
  &array(5) {
    [0]=>
    int(2)
    [1]=>
    int(3)
    [2]=>
    int(5)
    [3]=>
    int(6)
    [4]=>
    int(14)
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

Or like @JREAM suggest, you can use `array_walk`:

```
array_walk($data, sort);
```

Comment: Thats probably the easiest way.. I was toying with array_multisort and array_walk :)

Comment: Also possible, posted how to use it.